# Given an Object form a query with 100s of items. How can I find an item in the object w/o having to re-query the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

Given an object like contacts:

```
Contact.rb (id, fname, lname, key_tag)
@contacts = Contacts.where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

Given @contacts comes back with 1000s of records in that one DB query. How can I then get/see if a object exists in @contacts that matches a given 'key_tag'.

I tried:

```
@contacts.where(:key_tag => 'def12')
```

But that requeries the database which is exactly what I want to avoid. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: `@contacts = Contacts.where(:user_id => @user.id)` results in an ActiveRelation object, no query should be done at this moment.

So, your codesample should only do one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable find method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
@contacts.find {|c| c.key_tag == 'def12'}
```

Comment: Can't guarantee that, but they are inherently different. While `where` queries the DB, `find` will work with objects on memory and won't re-query the DB.

Comment: `select` will return an array of all matching elements, `find` just the first such.

Answer (score 1):

what you Have is an Relation there. So adding the other where changes the relation and queries that data back.  It should be lazily loaded.  So in your code

```
Contact.rb (id, fname, lname, key_tag)
@contacts = Contacts.where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

If you don't touch @contacts, it shouldn't even hit the DB. But once you try to get data from it, it will then be executed and data comes back.  If you are going to show all of them, you could use something like #all to return them as an array, and then use Array#select to search through it.  Depending upon the speed of the system and/or your db, it might be more efficient to the DB do the select.

```
@contacts = Contacts.where(:user_id => @user.id).all 
@contacts_with_key = @contacts.select { |c| c.key_tag == 'def12' }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried select and it was incredibly slow. Find was 4 times faster. Not sure why that is...

Comment: find only returns 1 element and exits after it finds it. so depending upon the data and where said element is in it, they could run the same speed (Element was last element in list). or really fast (element was first). But if only need the first element then find is what you need, if you need all of them (IE multiple keys, then select is probably collect). But the DB still probably faster depending upon tables/indexes etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try [Enumerable#find_all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all)

```
@contacts.find_all {|a| a[:key_tag] == 'def12'}
```

Or if you want to only find first one(given that key_tag is unique)

```
@contacts.find {|a| a[:key_tag] == 'def12'}
```

be sure to:

```
include Enumerable
```